# Data extraction from hierachial text using Python

Tags: python, hierarchical-data

Below is the example of my hierarchical data. Using python, what is the best way to extract all the entry information and save them in a table with rows and columns organized based on the hierarchical structure. Is it possible to perform iteration over each Cluster ?

```
Root_file { 
    Version = "1.1"
    Cluster {
        ClusterName = "cluster 1"
        Group {
            groupType = Type1
            Subgroup {
                country = US
            }
        }
        Group {
            groupType = Type2
            Subgroup {
                country = England
            }
        }
    }
    Cluster {
        ClusterName = "cluster 2"
        Group {
            groupType = Type1
            Subgroup {
                country = US
            }
            Subgroup {
                country = China
            }
            Subgroup {
                country = Germany
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like JSON, have you tried using python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html)

Comment: The structure is deeply nested, so basically the way to transform this into a 2D data table is a matter of your designing decision. Why not store the data as JSON entries?

Comment: The data is given to me like this. For those who suggest JSON, do that mean I need to save the data in JSON format first, then write codes on JSON format data?

Answer (score 0):

use json format. if you want to store this in a relational database i have no idea how to do it. but you could store the data as json using MongoDB.

```
Root_file = {
    "Version" : "1.1",
    "Clusters" : [
        {
            "ClusterName" : "cluster 1",
            "Groups" : [
                {
                    "groupType" : "Type1",
                    "Subgroup" : {
                        "country" : "US"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "groupType" : "Type2",
                    "Subgroup" : {
                        "country" : "England"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ClusterName" : "cluster 2",
            "Groups" : [
                {
                    "groupType" : "Type1",
                    "Subgroups" : [
                        {
                            "country" : "US"
                        },
                        {
                            "country" : "China"
                        },
                        {
                            "country" : "Germany"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **parser** for this data format. I don't know if it's a standard, therefore I don't know if there's a parser, but I came up with a parser that works *only* if the input if formatted as you have posted:

```
import re
group_start_pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s*\{")
value_pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s*\=\s*(.*)")

def parse(src):
    result = []
    current_children = result
    current_group = None
    for line in src.split('\n'):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue  # Empty line

        match = value_pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            # It's a 'key = value' line
            if current_group is None:
                raise SyntaxError("No current group")
            key, value = match.groups()
            current_group[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            continue

        match = group_start_pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            # It's a "Group {" opening line
            current_group = {
                'name': match.group(1),
                'children': [],
                'parent': current_group,
            }
            current_children.append(current_group)
            current_children = current_group['children']
            continue

        if line.strip() == '}':
            # Closing group
            if current_group is None:
                raise SyntaxError("No current group")
            current_group = current_group.pop('parent')
            current_children = current_group['children'] if current_group else result
            continue

        raise SyntaxError("Invalid line: {!r}".format(line))

    if current_group:
        raise SyntaxError("Missing closing braces")
    return result
```

For the given string, the output of this parser is a list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'Root_file', 'Version': '"1.1"', 'children': [
  {'name': 'Cluster', 'ClusterName': '"cluster 1"', 'children': [
    {'groupType': 'Type1', 'children': [
      {'name': 'Group', 'name': 'Subgroup', 'children': [], 'country': 'US'},
    ]},
    {'name': 'Group', 'groupType': 'Type2', 'children': [
      {'country': 'England', 'name': 'Subgroup', 'children': []},
    ]},
  ]},
  {'name': 'Cluster', 'ClusterName': '"cluster 2"', 'children': [
    {'name': 'Group', 'groupType': 'Type1', 'children': [
      {'name': 'Subgroup', 'country': 'US', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'Subgroup', 'country': 'China', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'Subgroup', 'country': 'Germany', 'children': []},
    ]},
  ]}],
}]
```